# How can i search a worksheet for specific values and make the cell bold if the value is present using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, search, bold

I am very new to coding, so please bear this in mind.
This is the project code in a new and way better version thanks to CDP1802!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wsSource, wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim i, iLastSource, iRowTarget, count As Long
Dim cell As Range

Set wsSource = Worksheets("Stig Jan")
iLastSource = wsSource.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Laura Jan")

count = 0
With wsSource
iRowTarget = wsTarget.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For i = 36 To iLastSource
  Set cell = .Cells(i, 4)
  If cell.Font.Bold = False Then
    If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
      .Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Copy wsTarget.Range("A" & iRowTarget)
      wsTarget.Range("D" & iRowTarget).ClearContents
      iRowTarget = iRowTarget + 1
      count = count + 1
    End If
  End If
If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
 wsSource.Rows(i).Columns("A:H").Font.Bold = True
End If
Next

iRowTarget = wsTarget.Range("K76").End(xlUp).Row + 1
For i = 36 To iLastSource
  Set cell = .Cells(i, 14)
  If cell.Font.Bold = False Then
    If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
      .Rows(i).Columns("K:R").Copy wsTarget.Range("K" & iRowTarget)
      wsTarget.Range("N" & iRowTarget).ClearContents
      iRowTarget = iRowTarget + 1
      count = count + 1
    End If
  End If
 If cell.Value = "Fælles" Or cell.Value = "Lagt Ud" Then
    wsSource.Rows(i).Columns("K:R").Font.Bold = True
    End If
Next
End With
MsgBox "Done : " & count & " rows copied"

End Sub
```

This part of code worked very well for searching and finding the value before, but I am having trouble merging it with the existing code:

```
Dim myCell As Range
Set myRange = Worksheets("Laura Jan").Range("A36:S1000")
For Each myCell In myRange
    If myCell Like "*STIG*" Then
    myCell.Font.Bold = True
    End If
    Next
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can just use conditional formatting. You will not need VBA for this if you do. Alternatively, you can place this piece of code between `End With` and `MsgBox` and it should work fine.

Comment: What trouble are you facing?

Comment: Ah, thank you for this. I think this will work perfectly fine for what i am trying to do! Didn't know you could use conditional formatting with text. Thanks!

Comment: Actually i can't use conditional anyway i think. Because it will copy the formatting to the other sheet. And the formatting should be green in the source worksheet and red in the target sheet if this makes any sense?

Comment: Or can i exclude the formatting from getting copied in the code?

Comment: Oh, just saw your Edit now Scott. Will check this out! Actually i think the ideal option for me would be exclude formatting from being copied and use conditional as you suggested!

Comment: Hi Scott, your suggestions works! But after trying out with condtional formatting, i think this would work Better. Do you have any idea how i could copy only values and not formatting?